# Jinja2 adding 3 to days for every month in calendar

Tags: python-3.x, templates, django-templates, jinja2

Seem to be having issues with adding days to the days of any month that is less than 29.  If the days are 30 and over I will add a month and then subtract the total days + 10 to get the new date.   Otherwise I want to add 10 to the days if it is less than 29.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you find yourself doing manual date math, take a step back. This is **never** the right solution. You don't know all the rules around time zones, leap years, daylight savings, etc.

Use [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) to add days to a date and [`strftime()`](http://strftime.org) to format a date for display. And for the love of god don’t do this in Jinja! Get the date set up in Python and then pass it into Jinja ready for display.

*Python file*

```
from datetime import timedelta
newdate = mydate + timedelta(days=3)
```

*Jinja template*

```
{{ newdate.strftime('%Y/%m/%d') }}
```

Comment: Problem is this.  I cannot import datetime because I am using a platform that uses jinja but doesn't support imports

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by "doesn't support imports." It's impossible to use Python without imports. Do you mean that you don't have access to the Python code which calls the template? Or that you can't install new Python packages on the server?

Comment: Dont have access to Python code at all.  It is purely jinja2

Comment: How is the date being passed into Jinja? Are you getting a datetime object?

Comment: I actually solved it.  Thank you for the suggestiion.  We are using a special type of software to do this.

Comment: hi @NickK9 , is there a away to this without touching the python code ?